# how to use array sas and no use proc transpose. tried using do arrays but haven't got get the answer

Tags: sas, proc

have a dataset

```
col     col2  a   b   c   d
001      A    1   3   5   7
002      B    2   4   6   8
```

tried using do arrays but haven't got get the answer. pls help

Need output dataset like this (please don't use proc transpose )

```
col  col2  col_new 

001    A    1
001    A    3
001    A    5
001    A    7
002    B    2
002    B    4
002    B    6
002    B    8
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `UNION` in `PROC SQL`.

**Query**

```
select col, col2, a as col_new from dataset_name
union
select col, col2, b as col_new from dataset_name
union
select col, col2, c as col_new from dataset_name
union
select col, col2, d as col_new from dataset_name
```

Answer (score -1):

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  array _n{*} a--d ; /* double-hyphen is a range of columns, left to right */
  do _i = 1 to dim(_n) ;
    col_new = _n{_i} ;
    output ;
  end ;
  keep col col2 col_new ;
run ;
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.